# importing data from MySQL using python and tkinter

Tags: pandas, tkinter

I am trying to import file from MYSQL, python and tkinter with input 
field order ID

```
import pymysql
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import mysql.connector as sql
import pandas as pd

def search():

    try:
        db_connection = sql.connect(host='localhost', database='northwind', user='xxxx', password='xxxx')  
        db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
        db_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE OrderID=%s" % orderid.get())
        table_rows = db_cursor.fetchall()
        df = pd.DataFrame(table_rows)
        df
        e1.configure(state='disable')
        con.Close()
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo('No Data','No Such Data available')
        clear()

def clear():
    orderid.set('')
    e1.configure(state='normal')

w1 =Tk()
w1.title('My App')
w1.geometry('500x200')
ptitle = Label(w1, text='''Order Details''')
ptitle.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)

orderid = StringVar()
11=Label(w1, text = ' Order ID ')
e1=Entry(w1, textvariable= orderid )
b1=Button(w1, text = 'Search', command=search)


11.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
e1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
b1.grid(row=1, column=2)
b2.grid(row=4, column=0)
w1.mainloop()
```

I am getting below Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-34-1f76a2830089>", 
line 38 11.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable that begins with a digit, which is illegal in python. Change `11` to something that begins with a letter.

Comment: Bryan, it goes to non stop loop, can you please check code and suggest complete code as per your expertise

Comment: @Juzar: how can it go into a non stop loop? There is no loop in the code.

Comment: If everything is right, i am not able to import it, can u help